# How do you pass information to a Checkout UI Extension (on a web worker)

Tags: javascript, web-worker, shopify-app

I am using Shopify's Checkout UI Extensions to setup loyalty. I need to make an API call to verify a user has points before a purchase is made. So I am intercepting the buyer's journey in the cart if they don't have enough loyalty points to make the redemptions they have selected in their cart.

With the API call I need to pass in a JWT token that I have stored in `sessionStorage`. Because of the nature of a Web Worker I cannot access session storage. I do know, however, that you can post a message to your Web Worker if you have access to the instance of the worker.

Because Shopify isn't super straightforward with everything and its not detailed in their documentation at all I don't know how I could send data to the Web Worker that the Checkout UI Extension runs on.

To your knowledge, is there any way to do this? I've identified the following problems that I would appreciate any help on.

1. How do you get access to the worker instance of a Checkout UI Extension?
2. How could you pass `sessionStorage` data to a worker?
3. Is passing a JWT token through cart attributes a sufficient and secure way to resolve this issue?